# Power spectrum and Fourier transform convention (cosmology, Gaussian random field)

Tags: cosmology, conventions, fourier-transform

I have been confused about the definition of the power spectrum in cosmology, mainly associated with the convention of Fourier transform. The most of literature I saw, they are using
$$ f(\vec{x}) = \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} \tilde{f}_{\vec{k}} $$
as the convention to the Fourier transform, and the Power spectrum $P(k)$ is defined as

$$ \langle \tilde{f}_{\vec{k}} \tilde{f}_{\vec{k}'} \rangle = (2\pi)^3 P(k) \delta^3 (\vec{k} + \vec{k}'). $$

Here my question arises. If I chose a different convention for Fourier transform, then should the value $P(k)$ change too? Or, should the equation defining $P(k)$ be changed correspondingly, to make the value of $P(k)$ remain the same?

For example, suppose that I took
$$ f(\vec{x}) = \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} \tilde{f}_{\vec{k}} $$
as the convention. Then, if I use the same equation for $P(k)$, its value will increase by $(2\pi)^3$ times. On the other hand, if I use the following equation for defining $P(k)$,

$$ \langle \tilde{f}_{\vec{k}} \tilde{f}_{\vec{k}'} \rangle = P(k) \delta^3 (\vec{k} + \vec{k}'), $$

the value of $P(k)$ will remain the same.

Which one is correct? If the first option (equation remains the same and the value of $P(k)$ changes) is correct, then should I mention my Fourier transform convention whenever I write down the calculation of the power spectrum?